# Check a list has set of values

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have two sting lists

```
List<string> list1=new List(){"1","2","3"};
List<string> list2=new List(){"1","2"};
```

What will be the easiest way to check if list1 contains the values in list2.

Comment: What should be answer that you are requiring?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
list1.Except(list2).Any();
```

Comment: That doesn't check if list1 contains the values in list2, it check is list2 doesn't contain the values in list 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try using 
[listName].Except(SecondListName).Any();

This should work.